# Loading destination anchor view - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently working on a website in which I want to show errors of various types in a popup box, the errors are related to form validation and form uploads. I have tried alot for loading that popup box using various calls like

```
$this->load->view('registration_popup'); 
$this->load->view('index.php#register_popup'); 
$this->load->view('#register_popup');
```

but all in vein. I have two pages 'index.php' and 'registration_popup'. The page 'registration_popup' is a part of 'index.php' file which I have sliced and include it in index.php. There is an anchor inside of index.php namely 'Register' when I click it I can see the registration popup. Now, my question is how can I call the popup box so I can show errors when a user deliver the invalid data or when any upload error occurs.

Comment: You can't use a view in this way. A view is just the HTML that gets rendered. You need to amend the incoming link to point at the anchor or use JavaScript to direct the user there.

Comment: Thanks Methew. Is there any way in codeigniter or any library which I can use to call this view using js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be a little confused on how views work. The loader simply includes a file in your `views/` directory that corresponds with the name you provide, and (optionally) unpacks an array so that you have access to your view data in the view. Each call (by default) just places whatever is in the view, parsed, into the output buffer.

For notifications, it's best to just set an error message in the array you pass to the loader, then include / check for it in your page. Use some JS to allow the user to dismiss the notification or have it hide after a period of time.

For instance (controller):

```
$pageData['error'] = 'The database server was eaten by an elephant';

$this->load->view('example', $pageData);
```

Then, in your view:

```
<?php
if (isset($error)):
?>
<div id="error"><?php echo $error;?></div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

You then just need a little JS to let the user dismiss the error div (hide or remove it), or a link to try the request again, or whatever makes sense in the context of the error. A little jQuery does that easy enough:

```
<?php
if (isset($error)):
?>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dismiss', '#error').click(function() { 
        $('#error').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
         // any additional dom fiddling that needs done once it vanishes
        })
    })
})
<?php
endif;
?>
```

That's a crude example, and of course don't you dare load jQuery just to hide a div :) But you get the idea. Just have a link in the error with a class attribute of 'dismiss'. As you can see, you don't need to include the JS if there's no error to speak of.

Optionally, you *could* include some additional JS to fire an event when the page loads, but that seems a little strange.

Comment: Best answer Tim Post :)